# Run two classes with main in one project

Tags: java

I am using eclipse and I have two classes with main methods.I want to be able when i click right click on each of them and click on "Java application" both to start in a different console.The problem I face is that the first class gets successfully started while when starting the second class it gives me error in eclipse GUI : Selection does not contain main type.When i check the second class configuration i see that it points me to the first class run configuration.It seems that in the "Run Configuration" menu you can set only 1 main class for a project.

I have tried creating 2 run configurations for each class in the project,however it still gives me error when I start a second class with main method.Any ideas how to solve this?

```
Here is how it looks , I have started the ClientStart.java with main and I went to check the SeverStart which I will execute next : https://imgur.com/a/2yQ1kQl and when I run it I get :  https://imgur.com/a/QLHiPy6
```

https://pastebin.com/eHDGnY5W -SeverStart

https://pastebin.com/Kd6eRgPW -ClientStart

Comment: Creating several run configurations is the proper approach, and without seeing which errors it "gives", doubt it's possible to tell anything more.

Comment: let me provide a screenshot.

Comment: No, a screenshot makes this not helpful to others who have the same problem as you. Best to make edit errors into your question in text form (if you must have a screenshot, make it an additional thing).

Comment: The thing is it is not code error, it is eclipse run configuration problem

Comment: Sounds like you are solving a problem with the wrong tool here. Why do you need/want two different classes with a main method in your application?

Comment: @Joel Please [edit] your question to include the full source codes of your java files, which you want to start from eclipse.

Comment: So, from screenshots, you have run configuration for `Client`, but trying to start it while selecting `Server`? I think that's where the problem. Try selecting client file. And, do both of them actually have the valid `main`? Can you start them from console? What's this `mainCmd` file that has compile problems about?

Comment: Selectin the other run configuration works indeed,however when i stop everything and start the first class then the second with Right click -> Java application it fails again.It is very tedious every time to select which run configuration to run,is there a way to map the run configuration to class?The mainCmd I just don't use it .

Answer (score 0):

Run configurations activated itself when you select one class having main method. It ran in my case when I rebuild the project.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit how it worked to run 2 classes with main method?

Comment: @joel ensure your project is build after making your changes. Whenever you select a java file in eclipse and select Run as Java Application, IDE will help you invoke main method of that file. But if build automatically is not enabled, class file for that java class will not be generated and IDE couldn't call main method.

Comment: how do I ensure my project is build ?

Comment: Try to log something in class which is working fine & then execute it. Check if changes are getting logged.

Comment: both log correctly in the log files , but what does the logger have to do with running them ?

Comment: Have you selected option Build Automatically in eclipse?

Comment: Yeah,it is currently checked